# How to add AngularJS 2 in existing Java Web project

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, web

I have some experience using AngularJS 1.x in .Net MVC application. In that project, we basically downloaded all required Angularjs min files and included them in project. We did not use npm or bower. It worked fine.

Now my next project is on Java Web application. This is an existing application with plain servlet/jsp. I want to use Angularjs 2 on new pages that I'm developing. But I'm not able to make progress on how to include Angularjs in this existing project.

Angular team recommends to use Typescript along with npm/gulp. But I want to stick to javascript and not introduce complications with TypeScript in existing project. I was expecting to download angular min files and include in my JSP and get going. Apparently I cannot even find link do download min files. [New Angular](https://angular.io/) website doesn't even have link to download them. I also looked up [angular github](https://github.com/angular/angular) but couldn't find min files.

I would appreciate if someone can guide me in right direction. At this point, I'm thinking to stick to 1.x instead of 2.0. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that is so annoying.

You could try creating a test project using NPM, add the dependencies you need, and then build the project. From there, you could copy paste out the javascript files you need.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Yes that may be the only option at this moment. Also it's hard to find documentation for Angular 2 for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can find angular2 versions prior to release here : https://code.angularjs.org but if you want the latest ones you will have to try Samuel's answer.

Besides, if you're doing this project at school and it asks you to use servlet / jsp, you should stick with it and use something like bootstrap for easier html/css. 
Doing the frontend with angular might be considered a cheat or a workaround ( speaking from experience )