# Angular2 in JSP ( Spring MVC )

Tags: angularjs, angular, jsp, spring-mvc

My question is similar to [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647361/how-to-add-angularjs-2-in-existing-java-web-project) i.e. A Web project is already using - Spring MVC + Angular1.x + JSP + JavaScript etc.

Page layout is already designed with tiles technology and I have to develop a sample page - only body part i.e. I have to keep doing layout with tiles and have to reuse - header , footer , left navigation etc .

So I set up a separate Angular2 project , build it and included final JS files in layout JSP of tiles.

In my new body jsp, when I use angular2 root component , my jSP is displaying perfectly but all other pages of application are showing this below error,

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.es5.js:2791)
    at createElement (core.es5.js:9172)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12146)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:12075)
    at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12760)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9858)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js:4763)
    at core.es5.js:4546
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.es5.js:1020
zone.js:654 Unhandled Promise rejection: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.es5.js:2791)
    at createElement (core.es5.js:9172)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12146)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:12075)
    at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12760)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9858)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js:4763)
    at core.es5.js:4546
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement
```

This above error is on console and those other JSP pages keep working correctly and this background error affects them in no way.

This error doesn't come on JSP page where I call root component i.e. my new jsp body page.

I have included angualr2 JS files outside outside body tag at bottom.

Any suggestions to remove this error from console and if this set up looks OK?

We will set up an automated process to build and copy files from Angualr2 UI project to Spring MVC project and only those final JS files will be deployed with app.

Its an Spring MVC controller which loads the page for the first time - a JSP .

Comment: The error simply means that you're telling angular to start an app using the `<app-root>` component, but there is no such element in the page, so Angular can't bootstrap the application. You shouldn't try to start the angular application on pages which are unrelated to this angular app.

Comment: On those pages ( JSP code ) , I am not using any angular tags ( which I believe means that I am not trying to start angular on those pages ) , only script files included. So how do I do that?  I included script files outside body too , at bottom.

Comment: That's precisely why you get that error: you're including script files that contain JavaScript code that tries to start an angular application by bootstrapping it with the element `app-root`. But this element is not on the page. So it fails. Don't include those scripts.

Comment: ok, so I need to include those scripts not on common layout but only on my body jsp. Will try that. Thanks .

Comment: In my body jsp, first I called root component , `<app-root>Loading...</app-root>` then included angular2 js files ...and that works without error. if js files included before root tag, error will be there. @JBNizet : if you like, you can put an answer that I will accept.

Comment: Whether you put the JS code before ar after the element shouldn't change anything. But without the code of the generated HTML page and the complete and exact error, it's hard to say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inputs from JB Nizet from comments , I am able to resolve issue by removing angular js inclusions from common application layout JSP and putting it in body jsp file as shown below.

```
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>

<!--  For Angular 2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js" > </script>
```

I am building application with - `ng build --env=prod --output-hashing none`

I if I do JS inclusions before calling root component, error occurs.